# Deserialization of externally loaded assembly types

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly

I load external libraries using

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);

foreach (Type assemblyType in assembly.GetTypes())
{
    if (assemblyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Chip.Chip)))
    {
        Chip.Chip chip = (Chip.Chip)Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyType);
        this[chip.Name] = new ChipAssembly()
        {
            Name = chip.Name,
            Description = chip.Description,
            Image = chip.Image,
            Type = assemblyType
        };
    }
}
```

It works fine. `ChipAssembly` is a helper which holds necessary fields + Type which helps me to create instance of it once user asks for it explicitly.

Now, I use binary serialization to save it to a file, including type. When I deserialize it throws `SerializationException`, saying that `AssemblyNamespace.AssemblyClass` is not found. However, when I force type to `AssemblyClass` when serializing, it deserializes correctly. I feel that I somehow assign wrong assemblyType, am I? :)

`AssemblyNamespace.AssemblyClass` is just an example of loaded assembly.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you need to load the assembly containing this type into the CLR before attempting to deserialize if this assembly is not statically linked to the executing assembly:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);
// the assembly containing the type is now loaded into the CLR
// => deserialize now
```

Comment: It is there, but just not under 'AssemblyClass' but 'AssemblyNamespace.AssemblyClass', 'scope' is wrong and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @aambrozkiewicz, is it the same class that you have serialized? Could it be another one that is loaded in the host assembly when deserializing?